# Cutting and pasting in MS Word: hourglass pops and it takes longer than expected

Tags: microsoft-word

I work with MS Word 2007. Today I created a new document, and for some reason cutting and pasting text (using Ctrl-X and Ctrl-V) takes longer than expected.

To clarify, here's the process:

- I select a single word in the document
- I click Ctrl-X
- The hourglass shows up for 1-2 seconds
- The word is cut

The same happens for pasting (i.e. 1-2 seconds of hourglass). This document is ~5 pages long, with nothing fancy. I have plenty of available RAM and my CPU usage is around 1-2%, there's not peak during the cut/paste.

Any thoughts on what can cause this and what I can do against it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens for all documents or only for the one you mentioned?
Some people complained about this problem and they said that disabling the add-in called PDF Complete fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

More about PDF Complete and Word 2007:  Had PDF Complete preinstalled by HP on a new computer and was pulling my hair out about how slow the text cursor moved with arrow keys (accompanied by a "busy" symbol during cursor movement).  Hours of sweating later, the problem was traced to the PDF Complete add-in.  Disabling the add-in restored normal text cursor movement speed.  To be on the safe side, I just uninstalled PDF Complete completely (pun partially intended).  My advice:  Stick with Adobe!